# Adding Barriers shapefile in postgres/postgis/pgrouting

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, network-analysis, pgrouting

Good day, Guys, I am new to the platform. Please can anyone give me a detailed procedure on how to configure my pgrouting extension so that it can recognize barriers and avoid them in my network after importing the barrier shapefile into Postgres

Comment: Easiest way to do so is, not selecting the lines which are intersecting with your road network. To do so, you can create a single multi-line string feature  by merging all features into one from your barrier shp. And then use WHERE ST_Intersects(road_geom,barrier_geom ) = false condition in you select query while you are using any of the algorithms of pg_routing

Comment: Welcome to SO. The approach suggested by Arun should solve your problem. If not, could you provide some sample data so that we can test it? Also add the size of your table and its structure.